# IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send an email with attachment when I access an action of ASP.NET Core controller. The attachment is downloaded by a site that exports an html page to pdf. The function sends the email but it can't delete the attachment file because it is still used by another process.
Where is the mistake?

```
public void SendAsHtml(string body, string subject, string emailTo, string url = null, string fileName = null)
{
    string path = null;
    using (SmtpClient client = GetSmtpClient())
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
        {
            From = new MailAddress(sendemail),
            Body = body,
            Subject = subject,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };
        mailMessage.To.Add(emailTo);

        if (url != null)
        {
            if (fileName == null)
            {
                fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss.pdf");
            }

            if (!fileName.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                fileName += ".pdf";
            }
            path = @"c:\temp\" + fileName;
            DeleteFile(path);
            using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
            {
                myWebClient.DownloadFile($"{htmlToPdfServer}?url=" + url, path);
            }

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(path);
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        }

        client.Send(mailMessage);
    }

    if (path != null)
    {
        // it does not work
        DeleteFile(path);
    }
}


private static void DeleteFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Warning($"Send email service: cannot delete file {path} {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dispose, dispose, dispose, using using.

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error? And what does the `DeleteFile` function look like?

Comment: @Jerodev I added the DeleteFile code. The error is raised when I call File.Delete in DeleteFile.

Comment: You disposed many things but still forgot one - `MailMessage` itself implements `IDisposable`. So wrap it in using also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try calling `attachment.Dispose()` after sending the mail message.

To do this, declare `Attachment attachment;` before `if (url != null)` and call `Dispose()` after `client.Send(mailMessage);` if `attachment != null`.